# Is this type of camera used to see who passes through a red light? (England)

Tags: uk, legal, driving, security

I was messing around on google maps (I live in England) and never seen this camera type before on traffic lights. Is this a camera that's designed to see if people run red lights or not?

[image]

[image]

Here is a full view of the junction, you can see this camera above the light in the middle

[image]

UPDATE:

Actually I believe this is a camera that catches those who go through red lights. So as the above camera is at a junction, would it be used to detect cars to change the lights?

[image]

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: Woops sorry! I'm in the UK

Comment: Looks more like a surveillance camera.

Comment: Do you reckon so, because of the nature of the road (accidents etc?)

Comment: It looks like the secondo one (because it has a flash i guess).

Comment: I have seen cameras posted on traffic lights to work as webcam for wild life, but if the lens of the camera is pointed towards the road, I would assume red light or speed control.

Comment: @Willeke If it was used to capture those speeding/running lights wouldn't it flash? It def looks like it's pointing at the road but it doesn't *seem* like it would be used to capture those running the lights/speeding

Comment: Modern road cameras do not need the flash anymore, different technology. (And speed cameras to give fines are not posted the same way in the UK as they are elsewhere but cameras up there might have technology build in.)

Comment: Interesting, I saw someone go through a red light a while back on this road at night and no flash etc. Doesn't look like the usual Gatso cameras so didn't know if this kind of camera had a different purpose. There's no other cameras around that point at the other parts of the junction

Comment: That camera looks to me like it's on a motorised tilt/swivel mount, I would guess it's a video feed to a control room somewhere.

Comment: @PeterGreen good shout, might drive by it tomorrow and see if it's pointing in a different direction. Wonder what it's purpose is

Comment: Many cities now have traffic control rooms, from where traffic light patterns etc can be controlled. This looks likely to be a feed for one of those.

Comment: Looks like cctv to me. Could be an automated surveying instrument monitoring ground movement as for Crossrail. http://www.topconpositioning.co.uk/news/case-study-monitoring-movement-crossrail-uk Or a sensor/reflector counting high-sided vehicles maybe?

Comment: I drove past it the morning and it was facing the junction where traffic comes off the motorway heading towards the camera. Must be some kind of CCTV or control room camera or something :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure that your second picture is a speed camera: if it is switched on (most of them aren't at any one time), it automatically takes a picture of any car exceeding the speed limit, and the driver gets a ticket in the post.

The first looks to me like a traffic camera, very similar to normal CCTV. (There is no particular reason for it to be on top of the traffic light, except that it saves the cost and congestion of putting up another pole.) There will be a control room somewhere, and an operator who monitors several banks. These are common on motorways, and not all that rare on dual carriageway junctions such as you show. The Highways Agency say this is to notice accidents and monitor safety rather than to issue traffic tickets; believe what you will.

Comment: Red light cameras do exist. I see no particular reason to think that the second photo is of a speed camera rather than a red light camera.

Comment: Second one appears to be a Peek Camera - http://www.speedcamerasuk.com/peek.htm :)

Comment: Speed cameras are normally yellow. There are some regulations dictating specifics of what each type of traffic camera must look like. I heard somewhere that the main reason for M25 average cameras being switched off was that they didn't meet the requirements of those regulations.

Comment: @AleksG There are loads of non-yellow speed cameras around - even some camoflaged ones. They are required to be yellow (as well as a bunch of other requirements) if the local authority wants to be able to reinvest money from fines in to traffic safety and management, but plenty of cameras were installed under other schemes witout that requirement.